# Xamarin: ArrayTypeMismatchException

Tags: c#, xamarin

Why do I get an `ArrayTypeMismatchException` with Xamarin for Android (MonoAndroid70) but not with Desktop .NET (WPF/4.6)?

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int MyInt { get; }
}

public class Bar : IFoo
{
    public int MyInt => 0;
}
```

Test code:

```
ICollection<IFoo> arr1 = new Bar[1] { new Bar() };
ICollection<IFoo> arr2 = new Bar[1] { new Bar() };

ICollection<IFoo>[] a2d = new ICollection<IFoo>[2] { arr1, arr2 };
```

The exception occurs at the last line at runtime. The compiler says everything is fine.

**Edit:**

The folowing types are working:

`IEnumerable`

`IEnumerable<T>`

`ICollection`

`IList`

The following types are *not* working:

`ICollection<T>`

`IList<T>`

Comment: Most likely due to how `ICollection` is implemented in Android. How you tried with other interfaces such as `IList`, `ISet` or a normal array?

Comment: Same with IList. I need an interface that is implemented by Array/T[] and List<T> because I need a common Count/Length property and the IEnumerator<T>. So only IList<T> and ICollection<T> fit these criterias and are implemented by both of them. And with both of them it's the same exception problem.

Comment: Using IEnumerable<T> throws no exception.

Comment: OK sounds like a framework issue which is never fun to debug. `IEnumerable` has a count property, can you just use that to figure out length?

Comment: Under the hood IEnumerable.Count() checks for known types first and then cast the type and returning the property or iterating through the enumerator.
Array and List<T> are known types as they implements ICollection<T>. I wanted to avoid that unnecessary type check and use ICollection directly.

Comment: Why not just use a basic nested array then? eg. `IFoo[][]`

Comment: In the comments above I described why

Comment: @Maas That is a Mono runtime bug that was fixed, but appears to be a regression... it should be reported https://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1120

Comment: The reported issue was accepted as runtime bug and moved to Mono: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/6266

Comment: Fixed: https://github.com/monojenkins/mono/commit/7597459bfece5b4ee7c670ebbe5193fb4156fbf6